# AzerothCore : Import the update of database

Tags: azerothcore

Hello I wanted to ask if, to import the .sql update (after a git pull) I have to assemble and merge with the bash file (app/db_assembler) or if it's ok if I just launch the worldserver.exe and he will do it

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer

No, the `worldserver` process will NOT update your database.

You need to use the DB-assembler bash script, as the [instructions](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/wiki/Database-Setup) say.

#### More details

This is different than in TrinityCore, where it is a feature of the `worldserver` process to update the database.

In AzerothCore this task is a responsability of an external script, written in bash, the DB-assembler.

The advantage of having an external script to do this task instead of the `worldserver` is:

- You don't need to compile and run the `worldserver` if you only need to create the database (useful when using or developing tools that only need the DBs)
- The DB assembler is able to **generate** a unique SQL update file per each DB (by merging all the single SQL update files), which can be useful for debugging or development purposes
- In general, it is better to delegate different software components for different tasks, instead of having a monolith doing everything

Answer (score 3):

You can also make your own merge script and apply manually. Or just merge with the db_assembler.sh then apply manually.

Else refer to Francesco's answer